# Angular and TypeScript: Cannot find name 'Note'.ts(2304)

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a notes app, when adding Note in the service I get the following: Cannot find name Note

This is the code:

```
export class DataService {

  constructor(private firestore: Firestore) { }

  getNotes(): Observable<Note[]>{
    const notesRef = collection(this.firestore, 'notes');
    return collectionData(notesRef,{idField:'id'}) as Observable<Note[]>;
  }
getNoteById(id): Observable<Note>{
    const noteDocRef = doc(this.firestore, `notes/${id}`);
    return docData(noteDocRef, {idField: 'id'}) as Observable<Note[]>;
  }

  addNote(note: Note){
    const notesRef = collection(this.firestore, 'notes');
    return addDoc(notesRef, note);
  }

  deleteNote(note: Note){
    const noteDocRef = doc(this.firestore, `notes/${note.id}`);
    return deleteDoc(noteDocRef);
  }

  updateNote(note: Note){
    const noteDocRef = doc(this.firestore, `notes/${note.id}`);
    return updateDoc(noteDocRef, {nombre: note.nombre, descripcion: note.descripcion});
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable, } from '@angular/core';
import { Firestore, collectionData, docData, doc, addDoc,  } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { collection, deleteDoc, updateDoc} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { Observable, } from 'rxjs';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```